# Proxy is ignored for localhost in docker selenium version: 3.141.59-zinc

Tags: selenium, proxy, webdriver

**Description:**
I have upgraded docker selenium version to **3.141.59-zinc** (from 3.141.59-europium), it started failing the acceptance test due to header info (set through proxy server) not found at server side. If I change image from zinc to europium - all works fine.

**Log trace with 3.141.59-europium:**
Remote address of request printed at server side: 127.0.0.1
**Headers:** {accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9, host=localhost:39868, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user=123456789, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36,
accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8, via=1.1 browsermobproxy}

**Log trace with 3.141.59-zinc :**
Remote address of request printed at server side: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
**Headers:** {sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9, host=localhost:42365, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, connection=keep-alive, sec-fetch-user=?1, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36, accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9}

**To Reproduce**
Create Proxy object with host and port.

Set proxy in webdriver capabilities.

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

Set Proxy header

proxyServer.addHeader("user", "123456789");

Access application

driver.get("http://localhost:/welcome")

Check for proxy header "user", it should be 123456789

**Expected behaviour**
I am setting header with user=123456789, which is not getting passed if using webdriver 3.141.59-zinc. If I manually call url using URLConnection with proxy - Its working (So no issue in proxy server).
And also If I use ip address instead of localhost, its working fine (proxy header available in request at server). So I guess, its ignoring proxy for localhost in the new version of webdriver 3.141.59-zinc. I also tried with setting noProxy with null/"" but it did not work.

**Environment**
**OS:** Oracle Linux Server release 7.5

**Docker-Selenium image version:** 3.141.59-zinc

**Docker version:** 17.06.2-ol

Note: Using standalone chrome in headless mode

Comment: Any help to fix this issue is much appreciated.